# Qual seria a estrutura de CSS. Como montar esse modelo de galeria?

Tags: css, animação, css-hover, css-animations

Gostaria de saber que estrutura CSS precisa ser aplicada para se ter o aumento de `div`s com uma boa transição de animação a nível de CSS de altura e largura, o conteúdo interno da `div` não precisa ocorrer, ideia é ser parecido como no link abaixo:

https://www.wonderlandindustry.com/

Código que tenho até o momento:

```css
main {
  height: 100vh;
}

.main_principal {
  height: 70vh;
  background: #0b4c81;
}

.main_cards {
  height: 30vh;
  background: #042a3f;
  display: -webkit-box;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.card {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px 7.5px;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all .5s;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}


/*ANIMATION*/

.card:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
  -o-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
}


/*ANIMATION*/

.card_info {
  height: 100%;
  background: #0b4c81;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <section class="main_principal"></section>
    <section class="main_cards">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card_info">
          <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card_info">
          <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card_info">
          <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card_info">
          <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card_info">
          <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Análise de sites externos não está no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic), mas os comentários continuam em aberto caso alguém queira comentar algo do site em questão. Você pode eventualmente [edit] a questão se tiver alguma dúvida sobre a parte específica de programação e, principalmente, dar mais detalhes do que quer fazer exatemente para que a pergunta não dependa do link externo. Talvez isto aqui te interesse: https://threejs.org/

Comment: Jack tirando esse btn de **+** que fica seguindo o mouse o resto da galeria inteira vc consegue fazer só com CSS, nem precisa de JS para fazer esse esquema com as imagens. Como o Bacco falou edite sua resposta, poste o que vc já tem de código, o que vc já tentou fazer e qual a sua dúvida ou dificuldade em realizar e assim podemos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Vc quer que fique exatamente igual ao do site de referência ? Ou vc quer seguir o modelo que vc fez, mas só ajustar algumas coisas, tipo não deixar dar barra de rolagem na página, e não deixar a imagem crescer para fora da página?

Comment: Que fique próximo a estrutura do site, vou seguir esse meu modelo para ficar próximo ao site.

Answer (score 0):

**Opção 1 replicando a galeria apenas com css**

Fiz esse modelo baseado na galeria do exemplo, ela é em `flex`, e o "macete" é que todos os itens tem `flex:1`, porém quando faz o `:hover` passa para `flex:2`, assim como passa o `height` de `30vh` para `40vh`. O resultado é uma galeria super responsiva! Exiba tb em "Página toda"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código usado para fazer a imagem acima:

```css
html, 
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    display: flex;
}
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
.box {
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 30vh;
    transition: all 500ms;
}
.box:hover {
    flex: 2;
    height: 40vh;
}
.box img {
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">    
    <div class="box">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
    </div>    
    <div class="box">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
    </div>    
    <div class="box">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
    </div>    
    <div class="box">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
    </div>    
    <div class="box">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
    </div>    
    <div class="box">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
    </div>    
</div>
```

---

**Opção 2 usando o seu código**

Como vc está usando `transform` e falou no comentário que pretende continuar nessa linha eu te sugiro controlar como o elemento vai "transformar" usando o `transform-origen`, assim vc controla o primeiro e último elemento para crescerem apenas para dentro da página!

```
.card:last-child {
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

.card:first-child {
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

No exemplo eu tb precisei usar `z-index` para imagem que crescer sempre crescer por cima das outras, e usai um `box-shadow` no acabamento, mas isso é perfumaria, o principal é controlar como o `scale()` vai funcionar.

**OBS:** Aqui dentro do snippet do StackOverflow não ficou legal, pois o seu código não está totalmente responsivo, mas copie o código e teste no seu projeto que deve funcionar 100%

**Veja abaixo**

```css
main {
  height: 100vh;
}

.main_principal {
  height: 70vh;
  background: #0b4c81;
}

.main_cards {
  height: 30vh;
  background: #042a3f;
  display: -webkit-box;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.card {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px 7.5px;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all .5s;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.card:last-child {
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

.card:first-child {
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

/*ANIMATION*/
.card:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
  -o-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
  z-index: 20;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

.card:hover .card_info {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}

/*ANIMATION*/

.card_info {
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="main_principal"></section>
  <section class="main_cards">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card_info">
        <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card_info">
        <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card_info">
        <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card_info">
        <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card_info">
        <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```